# Windows Forms: Datagridview cell value not updated when it is modified

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am modifying the value in my Datagridview cell but it is not gettting updated in the cell. I have tried dataGridView.Refresh(), dataGridView.RefreshEdit() and dataGridView.EndEdit() but none of them work. What am I doing wrong?

```
 private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView.Columns[browseDataGridViewButtonColumnName].Index)
    {
        var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        var fileNameAndPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        dataGridView[e.RowIndex, FileNameAndPathColumnIndex].Value = fileNameAndPath;

    }
}
```

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan, it's winform and so no need of calling `DataBind()`

Answer (score 2):

Change your last line

```
dataGridView[e.RowIndex, FileNameAndPathColumnIndex].Value = fileNameAndPath;
```

To use `Cells`

```
dataGridView[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = fileNameAndPath;
```

Comment: I fixed it by changing the last line to dataGridView[FileNameAndPathColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = fileNameAndPath; Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
this.dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
```

Comment: Please elaborate to say how it fixes the problem (read [answer] as well)

Comment: .RefreshEdit() method of the DataGridView and that solved the refresh problem.

Comment: put the answer in your original answer not in comments, you can use the [edit] button. Thanks